# How to make a ownerID override command

Tags: discord.js

How it works is that it detects if the person has the permission `MANAGE_MESSAGES`, if he doesn't then it will check if it has `"1234567890"` as ID, if he does it doesn't return and moves on into the code.
How can I do this?

I tried a code like this below but it scans both, so anyway how?

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES") || 
  !["507408804145528832"].includes(message.author.id)) return 
message.channel.send(noperm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the discord.js.org docs:

```
.hasPermission(permission, [explicit], [checkAdmin], [checkOwner])
```

Meaning you should be able to do:

```
if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES", false, true, true)) {
    DoSomething();
}
else {
    return;
}
```